# GetInstructionSize() BEA Engine using Delphi /Lazarus

Tags: delphi, disassembly

I see this :

http://s1.picofile.com/file/7828818488/LDE64U.pas.html

Now i want to use to disassemble and get instruction size, how do i go about this? I try something like this

```
uses
  Windows, LDE64U;

procedure getFunctionSize;
var
  lpAddress: LPVOID;
begin
  lpAddress := GetProcessAddress(GetModuleHandle('user32.dll'), FindWindowA);
  asm
    mov edx, 64
    mov rcx, lpAddress
    call LDE
  end;
end;

begin
  getFunctionSize;
end.
```

Comment: Could you also include a textual description of what is shown in the "I see this:" link?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do, and what is LDE (where is it declared)?

Comment: And IIRC, it is `GetProcAddress` (Proc = Procedure) and the second parameter should be a string: `'FindWindowA'`, so this cannot be your real code. Do not post pseudo-code. Rather post a [MCVE], i.e. something people can copy and compile too.

Comment: Oh, and instead of the cryptic link, rather link to: https://code.google.com/archive/p/beaengine/